# Dynamically create, animate and then remove multiple HTML elements in a Vue2 project

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

With Vue 2 (and Nuxt), on click of a button I want to show a little animation of a "-1" moving up a few pixels from the button and disappearing after a second.
Each time a button is clicked a new -1 should appear while the old ones are still in motion. That's where my problem is, I can create an animation of just **one** -1, but I fail to make multiple at the same time.

In **old** jQuery based project I have this, which works as expected:

```js
var $element = $('<div />'),
    x = this.randomInt(50, 150),
    y = this.randomInt(50, 100);

$element.addClass('animated-increment');
$element.html('-1');

$element.css('position', 'absolute');
$('body').append($element);

$element.offset({left: x, top: y});

$element.animate({top: '0px'}, 500);
$element.animate({opacity: 0, top: '60px'}, 1000, 'swing', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});

....

function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

New project is done in Vue2 and using Nuxt. I'm not using jQuery this time. Obviously I don't want add jQuery just for that simple animation. Also I'd like to avoid installing any additional libraries, is possible.
In the Vue project I've tried `transition-group`, but as mentioned above if I click the button before one animation ends, the second one starts and the first one never actually ends.
`game.monster.wounds` - is an array of values [5, 7, 3] that should be displayed and animated, hence `woundEnter()` function removes one value from the array.

```
<transition-group name="monster-wounds" tag="ul" class="wounds" @after-enter="woundEnter()">
    <li v-for="(value, index) in game.monster.wounds" :key="index + 0">
        -{{ value }}
    </li>
</transition-group>

...

woundEnter(target) {
    this.game.monster.wounds.shift()
}

...

<style>
.wounds {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.wounds li {
    color: #e11;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    left: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 4px #FFF, 0 -2px 10px #ff0, 0 -10px 20px #ff8000, 0 -18px 40px #F00;
    top: 10%;
}
.monster-wounds-enter-active,
.monster-wounds-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
}
.monster-wounds-enter, .monster-wounds-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(200%);
}

</style>
```

Is there a way of doing it directly in Vue or do I need to use vanilla JavaScript with `document.createElement` to basically recreate that old jQuery script?

Looks like I'm approaching this from a wrong angle and I got caught in this wrong thinking. I'm sure there must be a way in Vue to dynamically add multiple, independent simple HTML elements and remove them from DOM after a quick animation ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not far from the right structure. The first issue to fix is that your `key`s cannot be array indexes here. When you remove an item from the array, the `<transition-group>` won't be able to distinguish old item `0` from new item `0` and apply the correct effect. I've expanded each wound into an object with a (notional) unique ID like so, but of course you could take various approaches:

```js
wounds: [
    { id: 100, hp: 5 },
    { id: 150, hp: 7 },
    { id: 200, hp: 3 },
],
```

The corresponding HTML is this. I've added `data-id` and removed the parens from the `woundEnter` call to support the JS below. I've also added `appear` so that any wounds that are already in queue when the group first renders will be handled correctly.

```html
<transition-group appear name="monster-wounds" tag="ul" class="wounds" @after-enter="woundEnter">
    <li v-for="wound in wounds" :key="wound.id" :data-id="wound.id">
        -{{ wound.hp }}
    </li>
</transition-group>
```

The final step is to have `woundEnter` take the `target` argument from the `after-enter` event and use it to remove a specific wound from the array, not necessarily the first one, to maintain consistency:

```js
woundEnter(target) {
    const index = this.wounds.findIndex((wound) => wound.id == target.dataset.id);
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.wounds.splice(index, 1);
    }
},
```

[Here's a codepen with everything working together.](https://codepen.io/kdau00/pen/YzZYwdR)